# Heroku Postgres Connections on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

Been reading up on it, but not sure I totally understand how connections to Postgres work in Rails. I have up to 5 web dynos, each running 5 processes (Unicorn), so that would be up to 25 connections, and then up to 50 worker dynos through delayed_job, so that would be 75.

But when the worker queue grows and I'm running all 50 worker dynos, it seems like I'm hitting the Postgres connection limit of 128 and I imagine that can't be good.

Is it that the web dynos can open multiple connections per process? Can the workers do the same?

If it's to do with the pool database setting, for Unicorn is that the pool of connections per worker process or per dyno? That's not clear to me (as per comments with Corey), although it seems like per Unicorn worker process.

Is there a way to set the delayed_job worker dynos pool setting? I'm guessing that's the default of 5 as well.

Any good resources or solutions would be really helpful. Seems like PGbouncer is one option, or setting the pool from the default 5 to something lower like 1 or 2.

**EDIT: I mistakenly read the NewRelic logs as ms per transaction, but it is total ms for that category, so it's not slowing Postgres down, but hitting the connection limit is still not ideal.**

Answer (score 0):

A single instance of Rails can handle multiple incoming requests using threads, despite the GIL, so the default configuration is to open multiple connections to the database (one per thread) and manage access to them using a connection pool. By default, Rails is configured to maintain up to 5 connections in this pool, but you can tune the size based on your needs.

Normally I would provide this information in the answer, but there are a lot of factors to consider, so I'm going to instead provide links to two documents that you should review:

1. [Concurrency and Database Connections in Ruby with ActiveRecord](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections)
2. [Deploying Rails Applications with Unicorn](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-unicorn)

Finally, I'll leave you with some hard won advice: **Ditch Unicorn and DelayedJob in favor of Puma and Sidekiq**. Puma + Sidekiq are both multi-threaded and developed with performance in mind. Puma is the default application server in Rails 5, and Heroku recommends it as well. Sidekiq is the de facto background job processing library in the Ruby community and enjoys wide support and commercial backing.

Comment: Thanks Corey. I've been reviewing both of those links today. So if I'm not setting the pool anywhere, should I assume it's 5, and is there a way to check that? I'm still not totally sure how the database connections work. It seems like I can set the pool setting to 1 or 2 (as recommended in the concurrency/db connections article), and I shouldn't ever run into this limit, right?

Comment: Yes, you can safely assume that the max connections in the pool is 5 if there isn't anything in `database.yml` and you haven't setup configuration another way. Regarding setting your pool max size to 1 or 2, that depends on your Unicorn configuration; if you're using workers, those will each need a connection or you'll end up causing delays while a request waits for a connection.

Comment: Got it. I checked and it was 5, but updated it to 2 and will see how that goes. I set it in the Unicorn config file, so I believe that will only affect each Unicorn process. Each worker would still get a connection, right? Not sure I understood that point.

Comment: @Lev If you have 5 workers and a connection pool max size of 2 you will only have 2 connections per process, leading to situations where you can have 3 requests in process waiting on a database connection. This is a bad idea. Seriously, use Puma and Sidekiq. They were designed to solve these problems.

Comment: Isn't the pool per worker process though? Am I misinterpreting that? I also don't see how Puma/Sidekiq solve the database connection issue. I understand they may be better performance and use fewer dynos, but they'd still use the same number of database connections, no?

Comment: Apologies, I misstated re: threads (Unicorn doesn't support threads). If you haven't configured Unicorn to disconnect ActiveRecord before forking, then reconnect after the fork, you are probably leaking connections. ||| Puma and Sidekiq “solve” a lot of this by supporting threads and using the connection pool. You can have 25 Sidekiq worker threads sharing 5–10 DB connections in a pool with decent performance, and you'll save a ton of memory.

Comment: Got it, yeah that totally makes sense. I do have Unicorn disconnecting and connecting before and after forking, and agree that Puma/Sidekiq are more efficient memory and performance wise - that's just more of a long term project shifting over. You might be right on the pool of connections as far as being per dyno vs per worker process, have to test that and see.

Comment: Seems like the pool is per process, at least according to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13310714/unicorns-eat-up-mysql-connections-not-respecting-the-pool-size-rails?rq=1. Does that seem right? I haven't seen anything definitive, but it seems to be the case.

Comment: @Lev Yes, there's no way for a pool to be maintained across separate processes in the current implementation, which, at the risk of sounding like a broken record, is why you should use Puma. Switching would take under 30 minutes. Possibly under 5.

Comment: Right, just wanted to make sure that was how it worked. Maintaining a pool across processes isn't a requirement. Writing the initializer might be 5 minutes, but testing and making sure it doesn't break anything is more.